# How to display animated GIF?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019, gdi+

I have an animated GIF, I'm trying to display it but I couldn't make it work. It won't run and throwing exception `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x80000B00.` at the line `SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, (TIMERPROC)NULL);`.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    Image* m_pImage = new Image(L"spinner.gif");
    UINT m_iCurrentFrame = 0;
    UINT m_FrameCount = 0;
    PropertyItem* m_pItem = 0;

    switch(message) {
        ...
        case WM_TIMER: {
            //Because there will be a new delay value
            KillTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER);
            //Change Active frame
            GUID Guid = FrameDimensionTime;
            m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);
            //New timer
            SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, NULL);
            //Again move to the next
            m_iCurrentFrame = (++m_iCurrentFrame) % m_FrameCount;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
            break;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:{
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            Graphics graphics(hdc); 
            
            //First of all we should get the number of frame dimensions
            //Images considered by GDI+ as:
            //frames[animation_frame_index][how_many_animation];
            UINT count = m_pImage->GetFrameDimensionsCount();

            //Now we should get the identifiers for the frame dimensions 
            GUID* m_pDimensionIDs = new GUID[count];
            m_pImage->GetFrameDimensionsList(m_pDimensionIDs, count);

            //For gif image , we only care about animation set#0
            WCHAR strGuid[40];
            StringFromGUID2(m_pDimensionIDs[0], strGuid, 40);
            m_FrameCount = m_pImage->GetFrameCount(&m_pDimensionIDs[0]);

            //PropertyTagFrameDelay is a pre-defined identifier 
            //to present frame-delays by GDI+
            UINT TotalBuffer = m_pImage->GetPropertyItemSize(PropertyTagFrameDelay);
            m_pItem = (PropertyItem*)malloc(TotalBuffer);
            m_pImage->GetPropertyItem(PropertyTagFrameDelay, TotalBuffer, m_pItem);

            //Set Current Frame at #0
            m_iCurrentFrame = 0;
            GUID Guid = FrameDimensionTime;
            m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);

            //Use Timer
            //NOTE HERE: frame-delay values should be multiply by 10
            SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, (TIMERPROC)NULL);
          
            //Move to the next frame
            ++m_iCurrentFrame;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);

            //Finally simply draw
            graphics.DrawImage(m_pImage, 120, 120, 100, 100);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Most of the example I found is WCF or the functions are depreciated.

Comment: Probably because you're loading the gif over and over again in the `WinProc`, and you never also delete the pointer so you're making a huge memory leaks.

Comment: `PropertyItem* m_pItem = 0;` then `SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, NULL);` you are using null pointer.

Comment: You are dereferencing an invalid pointer, resulting in an attempt to read memory at address `0x80000B00`. A debugger will provide you with all the details you need to understand what's happening. Assuming basic familiarity with C.

Comment: Now I have an error of `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x880027EB.`.

Comment: It's probably related to the formula `((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

You can set `m_pItem` to global. In addition to this error, you have some other errors. For example, `m_iCurrentFrame` is always initialized to 0 in `WM_PAINT`.

And we only need to load the GIF image file once, and don't need to put it in `WM_PAINT`.

GIF loop play,

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <GdiPlus.h>
#include <gdiplusimaging.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

#define TIMER_ID 101

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Image gif(_T("spinner.gif"));

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL; // <= Do not provide a background brush.
    wc.lpszClassName = L"anim_gif_player";
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return -1;

    if (!CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
        L"Animated GIF player",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 1080, 800, 0, 0, hInstance, &gif))
        return -2;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    return 0;
}

std::vector<unsigned int> LoadGifFrameInfo(Image* image)
{
    // I think animated gifs will always only have 1 frame dimension...
    // the "dimension" being the frame count, but I could be wrong about this
    int count = image->GetFrameDimensionsCount();
    if (count != 1)
        return std::vector<unsigned int>();

    GUID guid;
    if (image->GetFrameDimensionsList(&guid, 1) != 0)
        return std::vector<unsigned int>();
    int frame_count = image->GetFrameCount(&guid);

    auto sz = image->GetPropertyItemSize(PropertyTagFrameDelay);
    if (sz == 0)
        return std::vector<unsigned int>();

    // copy the frame delay property into the buffer backing an std::vector
    // of bytes and then get a pointer to its value, which will be an array of 
    // unsigned ints
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(sz);
    PropertyItem* property_item = reinterpret_cast<PropertyItem*>(&buffer[0]);
    image->GetPropertyItem(PropertyTagFrameDelay, sz, property_item);
    unsigned int* frame_delay_array = (unsigned int*)property_item[0].value;

    // copy the delay values into an std::vector while converting to milliseconds.
    std::vector<unsigned int> frame_delays(frame_count);
    std::transform(frame_delay_array, frame_delay_array + frame_count, frame_delays.begin(),
        [](unsigned int n) {return n * 10; }
    );

    return frame_delays;
}

void GenerateFrame(Bitmap* bmp, Image* gif)
{
    Graphics dest(bmp);

    SolidBrush white(Color::White);
    dest.FillRectangle(&white, 0, 0, bmp->GetWidth(), bmp->GetHeight());

    if (gif)
        dest.DrawImage(gif, 0, 0);
}

std::unique_ptr<Bitmap> CreateBackBuffer(HWND hWnd)
{
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);
    return std::make_unique<Bitmap>(r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static Image* animated_gif;
    static std::unique_ptr<Bitmap> back_buffer;
    static std::vector<unsigned int> frame_delays;
    static int current_frame;

    switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        animated_gif = reinterpret_cast<Image*>(
            reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams
            );

        if (!animated_gif || animated_gif->GetLastStatus() != 0) {
            MessageBox(hWnd, _T("Unable to load animated gif"), _T("error"), MB_ICONERROR);
            return 0;
        }

        // Create a bitmap the size of the window's clent area
        back_buffer = CreateBackBuffer(hWnd);

        // get the frame delays and thereby test that this is really an animated gif
        frame_delays = LoadGifFrameInfo(animated_gif);
        if (frame_delays.empty()) {
            MessageBox(hWnd, _T("Invalid gif or not an animated gif"), _T("error"), MB_ICONERROR);
            return 0;
        }

        current_frame = 0;
        animated_gif->SelectActiveFrame(&FrameDimensionTime, current_frame);

        GenerateFrame(back_buffer.get(), animated_gif);

        SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID, frame_delays[0], nullptr);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, FALSE);
    }
                  break;

    case WM_TIMER: {
        KillTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID);
        current_frame = (current_frame + 1) % frame_delays.size();
        animated_gif->SelectActiveFrame(&FrameDimensionTime, current_frame);
        GenerateFrame(back_buffer.get(), animated_gif);
        SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_ID, frame_delays[current_frame], nullptr);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, FALSE);
    } break;

    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        Graphics g(hdc);
        g.DrawImage(back_buffer.get(), 0, 0);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    } break;

    case WM_SIZE: {
        back_buffer = CreateBackBuffer(hWnd);
        GenerateFrame(back_buffer.get(), animated_gif);
    } break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I still have an error of `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x8C002288` in SetTimer function. It's probably related to the formula `((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10`.

Comment: @Papilion Have you tried my code? You can create a empty project and copy my code to test again.

Comment: Yep, that's what I do.

Comment: Does it work for you? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

Comment: @Papilion Yes, it works for me. Please try to load the gif image using the absolute path, lIke: `Image* m_pImage = new Image(L"C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\spinner.gif");`

Comment: I probably need to check the frame of the gif.

Comment: @Papilion Try other gifs

Comment: I tried to use a different GIF with multiple frames and works. The other one is GIF but has only 1 frame and the error occurs.

Comment: So it means, to avoid the error, the GIF should have multiple frames or programmatically check if it contains multiple frames. If not, then skip the timer otherwise, proceed to animate the GIF.

Comment: @Papilion Yes. For a gif with only one frame, the code will return NULL when loading the second frame because the second frame does not exist. As a result, the access fails.

Comment: Yep, another thing. How can I make it spin or animate forever? The GIF is continuously animating however on the code above, it stopped after a few frames.

Comment: @Papilion I found a new code example, please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per as reading into the comment section, it looks like the error `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x80000B00.` at the line `SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, (TIMERPROC)NULL);` happened because the GIF contains only one frame.

You can avoid it by calling the timer only if there are more than one frame, for example;

```
if(m_FrameCount > 1){
   //Continue calling the timer.
}
```

Here's another example;

```
/** These are global **/

Image* m_pImage;
GUID* m_pDimensionIDs;
UINT m_FrameCount;
PropertyItem* m_pItem;
UINT m_iCurrentFrame;
UINT_PTR timer_id = 123456; //set your own timer id
BOOL m_bIsPlaying;
BOOL isPlayable;

/** Functions **/
void LoadImage() {
    m_pImage = Image::FromFile(L"C:\\Users\\username\\location_of_file\\spinner.gif");
    UINT count = m_pImage->GetFrameDimensionsCount();
    m_pDimensionIDs = new GUID[count];
    m_pImage->GetFrameDimensionsList(m_pDimensionIDs, count);

    WCHAR strGuid[39];
    (void)StringFromGUID2(m_pDimensionIDs[0], strGuid, 39);
    m_FrameCount = m_pImage->GetFrameCount(&m_pDimensionIDs[0]);

    if(m_FrameCount > 1) { //frame of GIF is more than one, all good, we don't want the error of `Access violation reading location`
        isPlayable = TRUE;
        OutputDebugString(_T("Image file contains more than 1 frame, its playable.\n"));
    }

    UINT TotalBuffer = m_pImage->GetPropertyItemSize(PropertyTagFrameDelay);
    m_pItem = (PropertyItem*)malloc(TotalBuffer);
    m_pImage->GetPropertyItem(PropertyTagFrameDelay, TotalBuffer, m_pItem);
}

/** call this function on timer **/
void OnTimer() {
    if(isPlayable) {
        KillTimer(hwnd, timer_id);
        GUID Guid = FrameDimensionTime;
        m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);
        SetTimer(hwnd, 120, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, NULL);
        m_iCurrentFrame = (++m_iCurrentFrame) % m_FrameCount;
        //Invalidate(FALSE);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
    }
}

/** call this to animate the GIF image, should be call before drawing the image usually on WM_PAINT. **/
void AnimateGIF() {
    if(m_bIsPlaying == TRUE) {
        return;
    }
    if(isPlayable) {
        m_iCurrentFrame = 0;
        GUID Guid = FrameDimensionTime;
        m_pImage->SelectActiveFrame(&Guid, m_iCurrentFrame);
        SetTimer(hwnd, 120, ((UINT*)m_pItem[0].value)[m_iCurrentFrame] * 10, NULL);
        ++m_iCurrentFrame;
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        m_bIsPlaying = TRUE;
    }
}

/** Function to draw the image in Window, must be call on WM_PAINT. **/
void DrawItem(HDC hdc, int xPosition, int yPosition, int width, int height) {
    AnimateGIF(); //This will only works if the image has more than one frame. Otherwise, the single frame of image will be shown.
    Graphics g(hdc);
    g.DrawImage(m_pImage, xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
}


/** Function to destroy objects and arrays, call this function on WM_DESTROY of WinProc. **/
void Desrtroy() {
    if(m_pDimensionIDs) {
        delete[] m_pDimensionIDs;
    }

    if(m_pItem) {
        free(m_pItem);
    }

    if(m_pImage) {
        delete m_pImage;
    }
}
```

Then on your **WndProc**, you can call the functions above;

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(message) {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        LoadImage(); //1. Load the image
        break;
    }
    case WM_TIMER: {
        OnTimer();  //2. Call on timer. 
        break;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
       
        DrawItem(hdc, 160, 150, 95, 95); //3. Draw your image, specify your own x and y Position, width and height.
       
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        Desrtroy(); //4. Don't forget to delete the images and free up the arrays.
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

With this approach, you won't get the same error. The GIF will play forever if there are more than one frame. Otherwise, it will only display the single frame.

The project example can be found from [this](https://github.com/SeynalKim/ExampleAnimatedGIF) link, credit to [SeynalKim](https://github.com/SeynalKim).

Comment: What happened if I used PNG or JPEG instead of GIF? I assumed it will display it correctly?

Comment: @Papilion It will play PNG picture in a loop.

Comment: @Papilion - Yes, it will display correctly. As you can see, the timer will set only if `isPlayable` is set to `TRUE`. In order to set it `TRUE` the `m_FrameCount` must be greater than `1`. Since PNG and JPEG contains only single frame, then the timer won't work or the PNG, JPEG won't display in a loop. See what happened inside the `if(isPlayable) {.....}`.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT No it won't. The timer will only work if `isPlayable` is `TRUE`.

Comment: @Polar Yes,if add a conditional statement to determine whether it is a frame, it will indeed only be drawn once.